# What does %25d mean in C

Tags: c

can someone explain what the 25 in front of d does in an printf command ?
I have searched the web but don't find a good answer.

e.g.: 
    printf("%-30s %10lu %25d - %ud\n", "unsigned int", sizeof(unsigned int), 0, UINT_MAX);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is the padding width.

Comment: There is so much documentation about [`printf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2017) it is hard to miss.

Comment: have a read through this [`printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and specifically the part about the format parameter

Comment: It defines the width/padding of the printed value. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%d indicates decimal value.25 total field width.

[image]